# Struts display tag foreach

Tags: foreach, struts

`paramspermsForm.objects` is a Arraylist of BO's. 
`people` is an ArrayList INSIDE EACH BO. 
I cant seem to output the items in the people arraylist.
rolename is outputing fine.

```
<display:table name="${paramspermsForm.objects}"  sort="list" class="result" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" style="width: 775px;"> 
    <display:column property="rolename" title="Role"  sortable="true" class="smalltext border33"/>
    <c:if test='${CLabel=="Criterion"}'>
        <c:forTokens var ="permission"  items="A,B" delims =",">
            <display:column  title="${permission}"  sortable="true" class="smalltext border33">
                <c:forEach items="${people}" var="item" varStatus="loop">
                    <c:out value="${item}"/>
                </c:forEach>
            </display:column>
        </c:forTokens>
     </c:if>        
</display:table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your code isn't valid. You have opened a `<c:forEach>`, but it isn't closed.

Second, to access th current row element of the table, you need to assign an uid to the table, which will hold the current element:

```
<display:table name="${paramspermsForm.objects}" uid="bo" ...>
    ...
    <c:forEach items="${bo.people}">
        ...
```

This is [documented](http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/displaytag/tagreference.html#display-el%3atable):

Comment: I had the foreach closed, forgot to paste it, but you're right on the money. Thanks